# How to preserve text formatting in RichTextBox like Bold, Italics, font color, font size, etc?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, richtextbox

I have created an application and for that application, I have designed a help file in Microsoft word. The help file is too long. So I decided to use the `RichTextBox` control in vb.net. I copied all the content from the word file. Now, I need to preserve the text formatting I have done in the actual file (like bold, italics, etc).

How can I preserve the text formatting?

Is there any other way I can display the help file in vb.net with properly formatted text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RichTextBox` supports **`rtf` content**, you can't directly paste the *Word* content in your `RichTextBox` .

You need to convert the *word document* into `.rtf` file. Best way is to 
use the save As dialog  in *Microsoft Word*.

Then you could deploy the document with your application and then load **`rtf` content** in your `RichTextBox` using [`LoadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f99sst7%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.

```
RichTextBox1.LoadFile("Help-File.rtf")
```

**Obviously**, it supposes  that basic formatting like mentioned in title (Bold, Italics, font color, font size, ...) are enough for this purpose, since the `rft` format does not support all MS Word features.

Otherwise you may have to implement your own parse/interpretation logic.

Comment: +1 That's a good and easy method I'd advise too. Question is how far someone wants to with formatting features. RTF (rich text format) can preserve every standard (not too advanced, like what you mentioned) formatting you can perform in Word doc.

Comment: @CsabaToth Thanks for your comment. You are right, my answer supposes OP wants to load rtf content (ie: basic formatting like mentioned in title *Bold, Italics, font color, font size, ...*) and be aware that `RichTexBox` control does not support obviously all MS Word features.

Comment: He mentioned basic formatting, so hopefully it'll be enough. Otherwise (and I was in that place), you may have to implement your own parse/interpretation logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

I converted the word document int rtf format using the save as dialog box in microsoft word. Then copied the file named "help-file.rtf" into the executable folder (the executable is generally present within the debug or Release folder).

Copy the file in rtf format to the application executable folder and then use the following function:

RichTextBox1.LoadFile("Help-File.rtf")

Here, RichTextBox1 is the name of the RichTextBox control. Use the function above to load the file into the RichTextBox control.